# Contacts on Safety Relay

Tags: relay, safety, siemens

I'm trying to replace [this Banner part](https://www.bannerengineering.com/us/en/products/part.60131.html) (an E-Stop Safety Relay) with a Siemens part that will do the same thing. Originally, I had picked [this replacement](https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/WW/Catalog/Product/3SK1111-1AB30), but became concerned when looking at the datasheets, because the replacement candidate doesn't have contact ports S11, S12, S21, and S22. Will it still work? What do these port numbers mean; is there a spec somewhere that describes them?

**Edit:** The input is 4.2 A of 24V DC from [this power supply](https://products.pulspower.com/us/ml100-100.html) (which is coming from 20 A, three-phase 230V AC power).

Comment: Please describe your application in more detail.

Comment: What details do you have in mind?

Comment: Like a circuit diagram or block diagram with what is connected to the relay, with currents and voltages

Comment: My boss would probably be very upset if I shared drawings.

Comment: You don't have to share the drawings, an example schematic would work

Comment: Usually, 10 is the first contact common pin, 11 the first contact normal open pin and 12 the first contact normal closed pin. And so on with 20,21,22. But that pin numbering is different, so you have to check the datasheet schematic.

Comment: Neither the Banner or the Siemens parts have contacts 11 - 12 or 21 - 22. I don't see a problem here. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Contact numbering follows the format

```
XY
 Y = 1/2 (normally closed) or 3/4 (normally open).
X = contact number 1, 2, 3, etc.
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f89lXH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Six contacts of a fictitious relay with their numbering.*

[image]

*Figure 2. The Banner safety relay terminal numbering.*

Neither the Banner or the Siemens parts have contacts 11 - 12 or 21 - 22. I don't see a problem here.

Section 14 of the [Siemens SIRIUS 3SK1 user manual](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/attachments/67585885/manual_safety_relay_3SK1_3RQ1_en-US.pdf?download=true) shows how to wire the module. There are too many configurations for me to guess the correct one for your application.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. I didn't realize there was a difference between 11 and S11 (I was talking about S11, S12, etc.) -- question updated to reflect

Comment: I've added a link to the user manual which will explain the Siemens module.